# Hour from DateTime? in 24 hours format

Tags: c#, datetime

So i have this DateTime? and what i want to do is to obtain the hour but show it in 24 hours format.
For example:
If the hour is 2:20:23 p.m. i want to convert it to 14:20 and that's it.

I'm working with Visual C#. 
Any ideas please, thank you.

I have something like this

```
public static string FormatearHoraA24(DateTime? fechaHora)
{
    if (!fechaHora.HasValue)
        return "";

    string retornar = "";
    //here goes what i need
}
```

Comment: "hh" in lower case is for am/pm notation, "HH" is for 24h notation

Answer (score 345, accepted):

You can get the desired result with the code below. Two 'H' in `HH` is for 24-hour format.

```
return fechaHora.Value.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Description as to why this works would be useful. Such as HH for 24 hour format as hh for 12 hour.

Answer (score 180):

```
date.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // for 24hr format
date.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); // for 12hr format, it shows AM/PM
```

Refer [this](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) link for other Formatters in DateTime.

Comment: Is there a way to have it show am or pm as text? Or is something I must add?

Comment: @ATCraiger You can add "tt" to the string for the text "AM" or "PM"

Answer (score 26):

Using `ToString("HH:mm")` certainly gives you what you want as a *string*.

If you want the current hour/minute as *numbers*, string manipulation isn't necessary; you can use the `TimeOfDay` property:

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = fechaHora.TimeOfDay;
int hour = timeOfDay.Hours;
int minute = timeOfDay.Minutes;
```

Comment: I like this method because it gives me integer values for calculation.

Comment: This was the preferred solution for me because I just needed the int from the hour of the day. Much easier then converting to a string just to parse back into a DateTime again.

Comment: You don't need TimeOfDay.  You can just use fechaHora.Hour and get a number from 0 to 23.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
//String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", dt);  // where dt is a DateTime variable

public static string FormatearHoraA24(DateTime? fechaHora)
{
    if (!fechaHora.HasValue)
        return "";

    return retornar = String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", (DateTime)fechaHora);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this, if your input is string 
For example 

string input= "13:01";
string[] arry = input.Split(':');                  
string timeinput = arry[0] + arry[1];
private string Convert24To12HourInEnglish(string timeinput)

 {

DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, int.Parse(timeinput.Substring(0, 2)), 
int.Parse(timeinput.Substring(2, 2)), 0); 
return startTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");

}
out put: 01:01
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
string foo = $"{time:HH:mm}";
```

Where I find this useful is if there is more than just the time in the string.

```
string bar = $"The time is {time:HH:mm}";
```