# How to format DateTime to 24 hours time?

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I need string from datetime to display time in 24 hours format.

```
..
var curr = DateTime.Now;
string s = ???;
Console.WriteLine(s);
..
```

The output result have to be: "16:38"
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hour from DateTime? in 24 hours format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023649/hour-from-datetime-in-24-hours-format)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Use upper-case `HH` for 24h format:

```
String s = curr.ToString("HH:mm");
```

See [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

```
Console.WriteLine(curr.ToString("HH:mm"));
```