# How to validate DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I must validate a DateTime with c#.
So I have build this code:

```
private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff";
public object ValidDate(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.Value == null)
    {
    return null;
    }

    var s = reader.Value.ToString();
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    {
    return result;
    }

    return DateTime.Now;
}
```

Now if I use this date

> 2016-06-09 11:20:50.125

it is ok, but if I try to use this date

> 2016-06-09 13:20:50.125

the date not is valide. The problems is on the hour. From 1 to 12 it's ok. From 13 to 24 it isn't ok.
How can I fixed it?

Comment: You may refer this-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785162/how-to-format-datetime-to-24-hours-time

Comment: By the way, in C#, there is no `24:00` representation. It is represented as `00:00` like _most_ other modern world languages/applications. Read: [Confusion at noon and midnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight) and [Midnight 00:00 and 24:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00).

Comment: Also from [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times): `Midnight` is a special case and may be referred to as either `"00:00"` or `"24:00"`. The notation `"00:00"` is used at the beginning of a calendar day and is the more frequently used. At the end of a day use `"24:00"`. `"2007-04-05T24:00"` is the same instant as `"2007-04-06T00:00"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock) format which represents the hour as a number from `01` to `12`. Use [`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier) instead which is for [24-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) format and represents  `00` to `23`.

```
private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
```

Answer (score 4):

Your format looks off. Replace the `hh` with `HH`:

```
private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `hh` in the format you pass to `DateTime.TryParseExact()` expects an hour in the 12 hour format.

If you have a time in 24 hour format you have to change it to `HH`:

```
private const string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff
```

with `hh` specify you want time expressed in 12 hours
Use `HH` instead of `hh` and it should work as you expect