# c# how Delete AM/PM from Date

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get Date Time of today without having "AM/PM"

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;
```

gives me

> 23/05/2016 03:16:51 AM

I want the result be :

> 23/05/2016 15:16:51

Comment: what string format are you using? Also, the times you specified do not match - 03:16:51AM and 15:16:51 are 12 hours apart...

Comment: Maybe he is trying to say that he wants a 24 hrs system format and not 12.

Comment: each day is 24 hours , so why you are saying 15 is wrong ? did you try to save DateTime on SQL

Comment: That line of code doesn't give you *either* of those outputs, because that line of code doesn't output anything.  All it does is set a variable.  The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format DateTime to 24 hours time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785162/how-to-format-datetime-to-24-hours-time)

Comment: @FirstStep: In 24-hour time the output would still be `23/05/2016 03:16:51`.

Comment: @ara 3:00AM and 15:00 are different times.

Comment: @user1666620, good catch, but I think it's a typo (OP doesn't care about AM or PM in general, he just want to get rid of them).

Comment: I agree with @Sin. That is what I meant

Comment: @Sinatr I know, was just nitpicking

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `DateTime` doesn't hold any formatting itself. When it outputs the date time, it uses your computer's locale settings to print it to screen.

If you want to change the way the date time is formatted, you can either change your computers local settings, or specify the formatting you want to use, like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: do you meant to use `"mm"` instead of `"mi"`?

Comment: Indeed. Spent too much time on Oracle :) Thanks @FirstStep

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Adding for reference, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9/3/2008 16:05:07" - english (en-US)
```