# how to return DateTime instead of string along with 24hrs date/time format

Tags: c#

By default DateTime type in C# gave time in AM/PM format, but I would like to return 24 hrs time format and same time I want to return this DateTime type instead of string like below,

```
  DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
        string timeString24Hour = localTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;
```

**instead of "string timeString24Hour" I want "DateTime timeString24Hour"**

How to achieve this???

Comment: First of `DateTime` does not have a format.  It just has a value that represents a date and time.  Formats only come into play when you convert it to a `string` representation.  And you are using `HH` which should give you a 24 hour value, so I don't see what your current issue is, though you should use `MM` for month because `mm` is minutes.

Comment: It is meaningless to ask for a `DateTime` in a specific format. A `DateTime` is just a number. It has no concept of format - until you *format* it, at which point the result is not a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `DateTime` is dispalyed in AM/PM  in **your** culture.

Because the developement environment always uses the current culture to display DateTime

[image]

But that's only how it is being displayed. The value within `DateTime` is the same - culture independent.

By th way `"mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` is invalid becasue `mm` are minutes and `MM` is for month

Comment: The culture doesn't effect that `HH` will return a 24 hour format.

Comment: @juharr right but I misunderstood the question, it's about `DateTime` and not `string`

Comment: Personally I don't think the question is clear enough for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
```

That is a DateTime type in 24-hour format. A DateTime is a number representing all of the milliseconds since January 1, 1970. From it, you can convert to any part of time, or any string of time. If you want to use a DateTime, though - there is no inherent formatting to it until you need one by using

```
DateTime.Hours/DateTime.DayOfWeek/DateTime.Subtract(antoherDateTime).TotalSeconds
```

if/when you need time in a 24- hour format. Just use:

```
DateTime.ToString("HH:mm")
```

from here: [How to format DateTime to 24 hours time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785162/how-to-format-datetime-to-24-hours-time)

Comment: a `DateTime` type isn't in **any** "format". It is a number. Just a number.

Comment: And OP is asking for a DateTime. Datetime is a number that contains all of the time information necessary to do anything. If you can think of a way to convert a DateTime into "24 hour" format while still keeping it a DateTime, then you should vote me down. Please read question. OP asked FOR A DATETIME

Comment: `DateTime.ToString()` by itself does not guarantee that the `string` will have a 24 hour format instead of using AM PM.

Comment: Give me 10 seconds to insert my source, please.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want something like `String.Format` :

```
DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
string timeString24Hour = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}", localTime);
```

Or shorter:

```
string timeString24Hour = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
```

You can find informations here : [MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i want DateTime as return type

Comment: instead of "string timeString24Hour"  DateTime timeString24Hour